# Отображение адреса в строке браузера

Tags: php, html

Суть: есть простенький сайт-бродилка, писался на php-js. Там несколько разных php-страничек, и после захода на каждую из них в браузере показывается адрес вида `http://site.ru/page.php?id=100500` или, скажем, `http://site.ru/doroga.php?id=100500`.
Можно ли как-то сократить отображение страницы до простого `http://site.ru/`, чтобы айди и названия конкретных страниц не были видны?
Глупый пример, конечно, но в полноценных браузерках адрес один и простой =/
Подскажите, как это сделать, кто знает =)

Comment: Возможно, вам будет интересна [эта тема][1]


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/14083

Comment: Спасибо, об этих настройках слышала, правда, слабо в них разбираюсь =/

Comment: Уж проще всё это сделать на ajax(javascript), если можно оставлять свои данные для связи здесь, то пишите : arsh-andrej@yandex.ru , расписывать долго, по говорим про конкретную задачу, постараюсь помочь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

До простого site.ru сократить нельзя без ущерба навигации.
Варианты:

1. `site.ru/название_страницы/` - делается при помощи `mod_rewrite`. Так делают все взрослые дяденьки.
2. `site.ru#Любой_текст` - делается при помощи javascript. Без яваскрипта работать такая навигация не будет.
3. `site.ru` - делается, опять-таки яваскриптом. Через ajax посылаются post запросы, которые в адресной строке не обрабатываются.
   Как вариант, можно сайт напичкать формами с методом POST, но это изврат.

Comment: т.е. я правильно поняла, что в браузерных играх используются настройки htaccess?

Comment: От игры зависит. Чаще всего они или cookies. Да, это, кстати, 4 способ, очень узкоспециализированный: запоминать где пользователь был, например, локацию, в кукисах.